# English pronunciation of Sanskrit gita

Tags: sanskrit, gita

I would like to find the Gita written in English phoenetics of the Sanskrit words. I don’t want an English translation per se—if that is also offered, that is fine. Anyone know of such a text?

Thank you.

Comment: 'English phonetics of Sanskrit words'? Do you mean you want a transliteration/romanization of it in Roman script ? Actually, there are many writers who add the IAST transliteration along with the ślokas in Devanāgarī script or they instead just use IAST alone.
For e.g. ज्ञान is in Devanāgarī script, in IAST, I would write it as jñāna.

Comment: Gambhirananda's translation of Bhagavad Gītā, Radhakrishnan's and many others have included IAST transliteration.

Comment: Checkout vedabase.io translations in English IAST by Srila Prabhupada(Founder of Iskcon and follower of Gaudiya Sampradaya)
His translations may seem a little bit imposing and biased towards Krishna Bhakti(personal opinion), so you can also check other commentaries at the gitasupersite website, an initiative by IIT Kanpur which contains numerous commentaries by various sampradaya acharyas in multiple scripts! Happy Reading :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.